# How to rotate a matrix using quaternion?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

Given the constant coefficient matrix $M_{3 \times 3}$, and a rotation matrix $R_{3 \times 3}$ with respect to the inertial frame. How to use unit quaternion $q=[q0,q1,q2,q3]^{T}$ to represent the rotation matrix R for the term $MR^{T}$?

Comment: Is a "constant coefficient matrix" different from just an ordinary matrix?  How do you know that $MR^T$ is a rotation, so that it can be represented by a quaternion?  Why do you think that "representing a rotation matrix for the term $MR^T$" means that you are "rotating a matrix"?  IDK what rotating a matrix means even. One usually says you are rotating things in the domain of $R$.

Comment: Q1: No.it's an ordinary matrix. 
Q1

Comment: Hi. Q1: No.it's an ordinary matrix. Q2:I not sure that MR^T is a rotation, but I am pretty sure R is a rotation. so I want to find a way that f(q,M)=MR^T where R is rotation matrix and q is quaternion. Let me give an similar example, when we rotate a vecor, we can find following relation: R*v =q * v * q^-1. we hope the term that I mentioned before can also be represented in a similar way. Q4 & Q5: you may right, maybe the MR^T is not rotating a matrix. but I cannot find a better way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understand the question correctly.

Assuming that $q = [q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3]$ is a unit quaternion, it corresponds to [rotation matrix $R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix), given by

$$ R = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 - 2 (q_2^2+q_3^2) & 2(q_1q_2 - q_3q_0) & 2(q_1q_3+q_2q_0) \\
2(q_1q_2 + q_3q_0) & 1 - 2(q_1^2+q_3^2) & 2(q_2q_3-q_1q_0) \\
2(q_1q_3 + q_2q_0) & 2(q_2q_3+q_1q_0) & 1 - 2(q_1^2+q_2^2),
\end{matrix}\right].
$$

Comment: Hey. Thank you for help. but this is the answer that I am looking for. Let me give an similar example, when we rotate a vecor, we can find following relation: R*v =q * v * q^-1. I hope there is a way to represent the term MR^T in a similar way.

Comment: Actually I have been study quaternion for a long time, For my question, there may be no answer.

Comment: One can use conjugated quaternion to represent the rotation $R^\mathsf{T} v = q^{-1} v q$, so I guess the answer to your problem is the following: $MR^\mathsf{T} v  = M q^{-1} v q$? As far I know quaternion represents the rotation only if $\|q\|^2 = 1$, and to express matrix $M$ in the quaternion form, matrix $M$ must be orthogonal one, i.e. $M^\mathsf{T} M = M M^\mathsf{T} = 1$, so this is probably possible only if $M$ can represent proper rotation.